# ReactPlayer won't show videos with same object in the array

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-player

I have project when put number of videos to play it will select videos from array and but it in buyList[], so when
put like 3 videos and click play  , works fine if the the objects in the buyList[] are not the same , but some time the buyList[] content same objects multiple time
example

```
[{"desktop":"desktop/1(MB).mp4","mobile":"mobile/1.mp4"},{"desktop":"desktop/1(MB).mp4","mobile":"mobile/1.mp4"},{"desktop":"desktop/1(MB).mp4","mobile":"mobile/1.mp4"}]
```

here all object are videos number 1 and videos should play and when click open next should play same video again since it is the same object number 2 , but it does not play second video

-
but if the buyList[] like this , all videos work perfectly as I want ,Click open next and second video play then click open next the 3rd video play

```
[{"desktop":"desktop/2(MB).mp4","mobile":"mobile/2.mp4"},{"desktop":"desktop/5(MB).mp4","mobile":"mobile/5.mp4"},{"desktop":"desktop/1(MB).mp4","mobile":"mobile/1.mp4"}]
```

here is my code

```
const handleClose = () => {
    setAllStop(true);
    setVideoopen(false);
  }

  const handleVideoEnded = () => {
    setOpenBox(false);
  }
  const handleClickMuted = () => {
    setMuted(!muted);
  }
  const handleClickOpen = () => {

    if(openBox === false && currentIndex + 1 < buyList.length )
    {
      setOpenBox(true);
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);  
    }
  useEffect(() => {
      setCurrentIndex(-1);
      setOpenBox(false);
      setAllStop(false);
  }, [buyList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setHeight(getWindowDimensions().height);
      setWidth(getWindowDimensions().width);
    }
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);
```

player

```
<S.Modal title={null} footer={null} closable={false} maskClosable={true} mask={true} visible={videoopen} mobile={width < height ? true : false}>
  <S.OpeningContainer>
    
    {
      useMemo(() =>
      (<>
        {buyList.length > 0 && openBox && 
            <ReactPlayer 
              url= {`videos/${width > height ? buyList[currentIndex].desktop : buyList[currentIndex].mobile}`}
              playing   ={openBox && !allStop}
              loop={false}
              muted={muted}
              onEnded={handleVideoEnded}
              width='100%'
              height='100%'
          />
        }
        
      </>)
      ,[currentIndex, allStop, muted])
    }
    </div>
    <div style={{position: 'relative', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between', height: width > height ?'100%' :  'calc(100vw * 4 / 3)'}}>
      <div>
        <Row justify="end">
          <S.ImageBtn 
            onClick={handleClose}
            translate="translate(20px, -10px)" 
            image_on={closeBtnOn} 
            image={closeBtn}
            width={50}
            height={50}
            className="exitBtn"
          >
          </S.ImageBtn>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <S.OpenNumberContainer>
            opening {currentIndex + 1}/{buyList.stringify}...
                                {/*opening {currentIndex + 1}/{JSON.stringify(buyList)...*/}
          </S.OpenNumberContainer>
        </Row>
      </div>            
      <div>
        <Row justify="center">
        {!openBox && 
          <S.ImageBtn 
            width={300}
            height={120}
            image_on={currentIndex >= 0 ? (currentIndex + 1=== buyList.length ? openAlLViewBtnOn : openNextBtnOn) : openBtnOn} image={currentIndex >= 0 ?  (currentIndex + 1 === buyList.length ? openAlLViewBtn : openNextBtn)  : openBtn}
            onClick={handleClickOpen}
          ></S.ImageBtn>
          } 
        </Row>
        <Row justify="end" align="bottom" style={{marginBottom: '10px'}}>
          <S.ImageBtn 
            width={60}
            height={60}
            image_on={openMuteBtnOn} image={openMuteBtn}
            onClick={handleClickMuted}
          ></S.ImageBtn>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  </S.OpeningContainer>
</S.Modal>
```